# Visual Studio Highlights when I don't select text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just got into the office, and booted up my computer to work on my current project.

I hopped into a class file, and selected (through mouse highlighting) a group of events to delete.

What happened though was it only erased one character. Wondering what happened, I clicked at the beginning of the selection and re-highlighted the text to delete it again.

So i just clicked randomly in the middle of the file, and it highlighted from the beginning of the first selection all the way to where I clicked in the middle.

I have rebooted both VS, the computer and insured that sticky keys and all other "accessibility" software was turned off.

**UPDATE**

When I click shift and try to manually highlight with my arrow keys, the cursor doesn't even move.

**UPDATE**

When I click escape from the selection it goes to the search drop down:
[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/9591/searchbox.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/9591/searchbox.png)

Comment: Is is possible that one of the shift keys on the keyboard is stuck down?  I would hit them each a bunch of times.

Comment: The shift keys are fine, this issue is only happening in visual studio.  every other textbox/textarea is working just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstalled VS and now everything is better.

Comment: This is not a solution to the root cause and only delays the inevitable return of the symptoms.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, and no return. I'm assuming something (be it a plugin or add-on) was the cause and the uninstall killed the connection between them.

Answer (score 7):

The same thing happened to me, I held down the shift key for a few seconds then while still holding it down I clicked anywhere in the open page in Visual Studio, and voilá, my mouse click was back to normal.

I imagine I had unwittingly activated some kind of keyboard shortcut but not sure which

Comment: I have the exact same problem which are occuring from time to time. The described procedure (holding down shift for a few seconds and then clicking) solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks ! you just made my day ! had to restart PC over and over again !

Comment: Holding down shift didn't quite work for me, but a combination of holding shift/repeatedly pressing shift/clicking on the page did work...

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem too.  I believe I found the solution: check your keyboard options.

Go under tools -> options, under the Environment subtree, click 'Keyboard'.  Then, you will see a dropdown with the label "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme".  If you select "Brief" from this, you get the keyboard behavior as described.  I'm not exactly sure what "Brief" refers to, but it certainly isn't familiar to me.

Change the keyboard layout back to (default) or another one to get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Brief is an 80's DOS text editor. I guess that people still like the keybindings.